# Casting Hunter's Vision on an invisible Hunted Prey

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, invisibility

[*Hunter's Vision*](http://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=773) negates concealment and the automatic hidden condition from darkness and invisibility, but what if your Hunted Prey is already hidden or concealed when you cast the spell? [Hidden](http://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=22) states the attacker "must succeed at a DC 11 flat check when targeting you with an attack, spell, or other effect or it fails to affect you." Hunter's Vision specifies that your Hunted Prey is the Target, and doesn't otherwise address the targeting.

I'm inferring from this that with a very common use case (your Prey casts *Invisibility*) you only have a 50% chance for this spell to work. Am I reading this right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You are correct

When attempting to target a creature [Hidden](http://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=22) from you with anything that does not bypass the condition (such as area effects), you must roll the flat check.

> must succeed at a DC 11 flat check when targeting you with an attack, **spell**, or other effect or it fails to affect you.

If you suspect your Prey may attempt to turn squirrelly, you should cast *hunter's vision* before they go invisible (as going invisible does not negate the effect already in place, and they likely won't know what effect your spell had* since they can't see their own nimbus).

*They would need Recognize Spell and a successful check, or to spend a Recall Knowledge action on their turn to identify what you did.